# Action Bar not showing in 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.2-jelly-bean

> **SOLUTION:** It was a problem with the image search icon. Android did not find the image for the search action , I had not added them in all the
>   res-folders , it started to show after that...

I am trying to add the action bar to a app and I am following the basic app tutorial shown in the [Google Developer Website](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)

I have written the following code.

> **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void openSearch(){

        System.out.println("TEST SEARCH");

    }
    public void openSettings(){

        System.out.println("TEST SETTINGS");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

> **res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

> **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sample.actionbarsample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

But instead of a Action bar like this

[image]

I get A options menu. Which shows up when I press the menu button while running the app.

[image: Screen Shot on Emulator running 4.2.2]

***What is that I am missing out from the tutorial, Or is there something wrong in the code?***

> **EDIT**

After doing what **beworker** asked me I got this result, still missing the search box.

[image]

Comment: try mine...will work for sure

Comment: @mohit yes I did as you suggested the screen shot is after those changes as well

Answer (score 8):

Nothing wrong either with you code or with the tutorial. It's all about configuration of your emulator. You need to configure your emulator in the way, that it has software buttons. Switch to "Device Definition" tab and edit device that is uses "Software" buttons as in the picture below.

[image]

Alternatively you can simply uncheck "Keyboard / Hardware keyboard present" property in ADV configuration (see picture below) and restart your emulator.

[image]

Android 4.0 emulates old-style menu, if a hardware menu button is present. That is why all menu actions will go in there. If you disable hardware menu in emulator, then actions will go to action bar, as expected.

Please note, that on phones with hardware menu buttons like Samsung G2, G3 etc. menu popup will still appear and you cannot change this in your code. Android will decide what is better for user experience on each and every device.

**Update**

Another note. If you use compatibility library, make sure you use `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and `yourapp:showAsAction="always"` as described below.

> However, if your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on
>   versions as low as Android 2.1, the showAsAction attribute is not
>   available from the android: namespace. Instead this attribute is
>   provided by the Support Library and you must define your own XML
>   namespace and use that namespace as the attribute prefix.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="always"  />
    ...
</menu>
```

Comment: I did as you said..I did get the action bar but the search bar is missing even after doing what @mohit suggested in his answer.

Comment: android:showAsAction="always" on item with @+id/action_search will make "Search" item to be always shown, If you need a search box, then you need to do more.

Comment: the search icon is not showing up along side the options button as show in the first picture of the action bar.

Comment: I have its the `main_activity_actions.xml` file.

Comment: What is ActionBarActivity you extends? Do you use compatibility library?

Comment: my import statement `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`

I think its is the compatible library.

Comment: Ok. See update in my answer. You need to use `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and `yourapp:showAsAction="always"` in your xml.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36127/discussion-between-sangeet-menon-and-beworker)

Answer (score 1):

> **What is that I am missing out from the tutorial, Or is there something wrong in the code?**

Yes, there is a difference. 
Try to remove the **sample** word from your project.

Actually your project name is occupying all the space and in **search menu item** you have asked the system to provide the space if there is any room/space available which is not due to the long project name(may be activity or whatever) in your case.

So either change your project name to something small or use "always" like this:

```
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: I changed it to `android:showAsAction="always"` and also edited the appName in `strings.xml` to `<string name="app_name"></string>` still no search box.

Comment: It is the screen shot after applying your update...Its actually both suggestions included...

Comment: one more check try using mine only.Reset the emulator back.